# How do I create a sub-LeafSystem within another LeafSystem?

Tags: drake

I need to create a `LeafSystem` which itself contains another sub-`LeafSystem` (a `SimpleCar` in my case) such that some inputs is passed to SimpleCar and the outputs of `SimpleCar` is combined with some other processing to produce the final output of my `LeafSystem`.

I'm guessing I need to create a `Diagram` within my `LeafSystem` and create something like a "bypass" port that pipes inputs to outputs so I can use `Connect` to wire them up.  Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "System that contains another System" is exactly the definition of a Diagram in Drake. Consider making the top level a Diagram rather than a LeafSystem. Then you can use `Connect` to feed a Diagram's input port to an internal LeafSystem, and to forward an internal output port to a Diagram output port.

Comment: Totally agree.  And the DiagramBuilder should let you export inputs/outputs of your subsystem to be inputs/outputs of your diagram.  There are also a lot of blocks in systems/primitives that can help you wire things up.

Comment: I assume `Diagram` is intended to only do wiring and that any "processing" should be done in `LeafSystem`?   So if I wanted to take my `SimpleCarState` output from my `SimpleCar` subsystem and package it into `MyCustomState` as output for my entire diagram, I would have to add another sub-system to do the packaging, is that correct?

Comment: Right. There is very little provision for computation in a Diagram. We are contemplating some extensions in that direction but for now if you have anything substantial to do you need to do it in a LeafSystem.